# How to search for multiple words with one query?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, where-clause, sql-like

I am trying to make a simple php search using the following query. This works perfectly however the query only gives results for the first word. Would there be a way to get a combined result for all three words using a single query?

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE (wallname LIKE :searchq1 OR :searchq2 OR :searchq3) LIMIT :stat, :limt");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the `expr like val` pattern:

```
WHERE wallname LIKE :searchq1 OR wallname LIKE :searchq2 OR wallname LIKE :searchq3
```

What happends with your original code is that it is interpreted as:

```
WHERE 
    (wallname LIKE :searchq1)
    OR (:searchq2)
    OR (:searchq3)
```

So basically the last two search terms are evaluated in boolean context, as if they were conditions. If one of the search terms starts with `1`, it is evaluated as true (and all rows in the table will be returned); else if neither starts with `1`, the conditions are false, hence only the first condition comes into play (which is what you are seeing).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `OR` in the way you show. `:searchq2` is not a valid where expression. You need to do the following:

```
wallname LIKE :searchq1 OR wallname LIKE :searchq2 OR wallname LIKE :searchq3
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider regular expressions.  You could express what you want as:

```
where wallname regexp concat('^', concat_ws('|', :searchq1, :searchq2, :searchq3), '$')
```

assuming that the parameters do not have special characters in them.

However, perhaps you should consider one regular expression.  Then you could express the condition as:

```
where allname regexp '^abc|def|ghi$')
```

Comment: this is a way cleaner approach +1 for this answer. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

If You want to decrease query execution time, use UNION ALL (as many parts to union as 'OR' appearences).
Otherwise (transparent and short script) use all conditions in one line - as above.

Comment: interesting, what would the query look like with your method?

Comment: Hi. Sorry, just UNION instead of UNION ALL. So, sth like this: SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE :searchq1 UNION SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE :searchq2 UNION SELECT * FROM walldb WHERE wallname LIKE :searchq3